# Understanding registerCallback() from TF MessageFilter tutorial

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, boost, tutorials, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going through the TF [MessageFilter tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Using%20Stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf%3A%3AMessageFilter) and I understand the code except for line 13:

```
tf_filter_->registerCallback( boost::bind(&PoseDrawer::msgCallback, this, _1) );
```

I'm more of a novice when it comes to using the `boost` libraries, but after reading some documentation, it seems that this line is creating a function object that equates to something of this form: `msgCallback(this, _1)` where `this` is the PoseDrawer object and `_1` is a placeholder that will be substituted with the first argument provided to the function object (which I'm assuming is done by the TF library under the hood).

What I'm confused about is how you know to provide the `this` object and that the callback function needs an `_1` placeholder. Is the `_1` simply because the callback function (shown below) only takes one argument? If my callback function had no parameters, would I just remove the `_1` argument when calling the function? Why is the `this` object necessary?

```
void msgCallback(const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PointStamped>& point_ptr)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311665/understanding-registercallback()-from-tf-messagefilter-tutorial/) by [jwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38683/jwin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-12-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-29**:
These are all C++ questions and not directly related to ROS. I would however recommend reading up on C++ Lamba functions to understand exactly what they do. [This tutorial](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/lambdas-in-c11/240168241) is a good start.

**Comment by [jwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38683/jwin/) on 2018-12-29**:
Ok sorry about that. Do you think I should post this somewhere else? I posted here because this was code directly given in the ROS TF MessageFilters tutorial and thought it might help someone else going through the tutorials.

**Comment by [jwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38683/jwin/) on 2018-12-29**:
Also, I looked at the Lambda functions tutorial you linked. Could you specify how my question is related? I don't think the code above is using Lambda functions. I think the `registerCallback` line is just calling a function within a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You first need to understand the boost binding function and how use it to bind function object.

```
tf_filter_->registerCallback( boost::bind(&PoseDrawer::msgCallback, this, _1) );
```

Simply put, it binds the call back function with the function whose object being created pointed by a `this` pointer. Do a review on boost::bind to understand the syntax and usage. `PoseDrawer` is the class that has a member function `msgCallback`. `_1` means the default argument passing when the `rospin()` is activated up on the scope of the current subscriber. For the `tf::MessageFilters` tutorial, it is the `turtle_point_stamped` topic.

In summary, `registerCallback` is a way to bind the object function `msgCallback` of the current object of class `PoseDrawer` to the default handle of topic `turtle_point_stamped`.

---

Originally posted by [drNoob13](https://answers.ros.org/users/40829/drnoob13/) with karma: 36 on 2019-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1